# TypeError in python which says that dict object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, keyword-argument

I'm new to Python. I am getting the error `TypeError:dict object is not callable`. I haven't used dictionary anywhere in my code.

```
def new_map(*arg1, **func): 
    result = []
    for x in arg1:
        result.append(func(x))
    return result
```

I tried calling this function as follows:

`new_map([-10], func=abs)`

But when I run it, I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using arbitrary arguments when they are not required. You can simply define your function with arguments `arg1` and `func`:

```
def new_map(arg1, func):
    result = []
    for x in arg1:
        result.append(func(x))
    return result

res = new_map([-10], abs)

print(res)

[10]
```

For detailed guidance on how to use `*` or `**` operators with function arguments see the following posts:

- [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)
- [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for
  parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for you help but arg1 is iterable here. So I had put *arg1. How to differentiate key word argument from positional argument if I don't put  a * before func?

Comment: Try it, test it, you don't need `*`! You have 2 arguments, one of them is an iterable, the other is a function. Your function doesn't need to unpack arbitrary arguments, because they are well defined.

Comment: when tried to test your code with the following test case:               
         new_map(-10, -20, -30, func=abs).                                                             
 It shows the following error:                                                 
  new_map() takes 1 positional argument but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

Comment: Use input `[-10, -20, -30]` instead, i.e.  `new_map([-10, -20, -30], abs)`. Don't choose lists or unpacked elements arbitrarily, stick with one or the other.

Comment: Since the arbitrary argument may vary for each test case, I have used it that way

Comment: Your function will be overly and unnecessarily complex if you use `[-10]` in one case or `-10` in another. This is just an opinion to make your life easier :)

Answer (score 1):

The `**` prefix says that all of the keyword arguments to your function should be grouped into a `dict` called `func`. So `func` is a `dict` and `func(x)` is an attempt to call the `dict` and fails with the error given.

Answer (score 0):

You *have* used a dictionary by mistake. When you defined `new_map(*arg1, **func)`, the `func` variable gathers the named parameter given during the function call. If `func` is supposed to be a function, put it as first argument, without `*` or `**`

Answer (score 0):

`func` is a `dictionary` in your program. If you want to access value of it then you should use `[]` not `()`. Like:

```
def new_map(*arg1, **func): 
    result = []
    for x in arg1:
        result.append(func[x]) #use [], not ()
    return result
```

If `func` is a `function` to your program then you should write:

```
def new_map(*arg1, func): 
    result = []
    for x in arg1:
        result.append(func(x)) #use [], not ()
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a simple list comprehension:

```
def new_map(arg1, func):
    return [func(i) for i in arg1]

out = new_map([-10], func=abs)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[10]
```